# Should i use regular expression in this situation?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a xml file containing certain expressions like this :-

```
1. AAaaaaa-1111 
2. AAaaa-1111-aaa 
3. AA11111-11111 
4. AA111-111-111111
```

**(AA static text) (aaaa-Any alphabet only) then hyphen (1111 - any digit only)**

I was thinking i should write regular expression for these I believe regex should be the right approach.

But this XML file is dynamic. User can remove or add different expressions in the list. So How can i use regular expression here? Is there any dynamic regular expression kind of thing. Show me the light here please.

**UPDATE:-** I am using these expressions to validate user input. So whatever user is entering in a box, it should be matched with any of these expressions from the list.

For Example:-

If user enters

> AAabc-4567-trr

, then it should be validated coz it matches with 2nd expression in the list

Comment: @user , what is your requirement?? i mean do you want to extract the the values from xml or so

Comment: Why don't you show us some of this XML? Would be handy to see.

Comment: Could you give us a few more details? You have an XML file and in it the strings you mentioned. And you want to do what exactly? Search for them?

Comment: I think you'd need to better describe what you need to extract from the data for a meaningful answer. One option to add to your list is my [sscanf replacement for C#](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net).

Comment: "2nd expression in the list"... but the "list" isn't XML. Do we have to guess the structure of your XML? Wouldn't it be better to post an example of it with your question? It would be a whole bunch easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

What I assume from your question is that:

`A` is the letter `A`
`a` is any letter
`1` is any number

That's the only way I see `AAabc-4567-trr` matches `AAaaa-1111-aaa`

**Is that correct?**

If it is correct, yes, you could use Regular Expressions. What you need to do is translate **your patterns** to **regex patterns**. Assuming you have a new pattern:

`AAA-aaa-111`

to obtain the regex that will recognize that pattern, all you have to do is translate that pattern into regex patterns. For example:

```
string xmlPattern = "AAA-aaa-111"
string regexPattern = xmlPattern.Replace("a", "[a-zA-Z]").Replace("1", @"\d");
```

**Edit:**
You should take in count other characters that have special meanings in Regular Expressions, and translate/encode them properly. Maybe classify them. For example, these characters:

`.`, `$`, `^`

can be easily translated to regex patterns just encoding them with a `\` before, so they will become:

`\.`, `\$`, `\^`, ...

If you can specify what is the format of the validation patterns you are storing in the XML files, I could help you a little more, but I'm just writing this answer kind of blind ;)

Comment: The regular expression needs to be anchored with `^` and `$` to prevent inputs like "boogers-123" matching a pattern like "aaa-111".

Comment: @Quick In case he needs all the string to match only a pattern, yes, you're totally right, but maybe he wants to find matches in a text, don't know. He doesn't really explain it :). There are more details too. He will have to take a look at the **C#** regex specs and make a good bijection

Comment: @user732853 Okay, but remember, you must be clear about your validation patterns. You must specify what is the meaning of each character in your patterns. I mean, what is supposed to match an `A`? What is supposed to match the pattern `17SSFF$$(@*#`? Otherwise you won't be able to obtain a regular expression...

Comment: Good point, Oscar. The OP's update indicated that the input was coming from a text box, so `^...$` is probably correct, otherwise `\b(...)\b` (note the use of captures) would be required to extract the value.

Comment: Quick: Just curious what is OP?

Comment: It means "original poster", as far as I know. @Quick Joe Smith, @Oscar Mederos: If the task is to find these strings in larger text bodies, you could use `\b` word boundary anchors instead of `^` and `$`. Just make sure to use verbatim strings (`@"\b"`) or you'll mess up the escaping.

Comment: Yes, I suggested the use of word boundaries. :)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions that match certain sets of characters in a certain order are fairly simple. For example, this will match #2 (AAaaa-1111-aaa):

```
[A-Z]{2}[a-z]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[a-z]{3}
```

Breaking it down:

- `[A-Z]`: Any character from A to Z. So any alphabetic, uppercase character.
- `{2}`: Two of the previous item.

The rest of it works in the same way. The hyphens between things are there to match the hyphens in your expected input.

Comment: If OP is really asking "How do I parse XML with regex", should we really provide the answer, or steer them to a better solution?

Comment: No, they're not. They're storing validation expressions in an XML file. That is the extent of XML's involvement here.

Comment: @Quick That's what I understood too :/

Comment: Hi Quick, Oscar. The expressions are coming from the XML File. But expressions are dynamic. User can edit/delete/modify expression. So What i need is to build a regular expression dynamically and validate the user's input.